# What does it mean if my computed values for a metric is negative?

Tags: metric-spaces

I am trying to compute the normalized information distance (statistical correlation between two random variables)

[Normalized information Distance formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl9jm.png)

H(X), H(Y ), and H(X, Y ) denote the entropy of X, the
entropy of Y, and the joint entropy of {X, Y }, respectively. It is a true metric and hence follows the non-negativity property.

But when I try to compute the value for this metric, I am getting my value to be below 0. I am not sure how to proceed with this

- What does it mean to have a negative value for a matric that can only be between 0 and 1
- I have checked my computation of NID and it seems to be correct to me

Comment: You should post your computation. Joint entropy has the property that $H(X,Y) \geq 0$ and $H(X,Y) \geq \max\{H(X),H(Y)\}$, so the formula you posted will never give a negative number.

Comment: By the definition of a metric, it is always nonnegative and positive for different points.  Either the formula you have been given is not a metric or you are computing it incorrectly.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can it be possible that the data points of Variable X and Y that we are comparing could be wrong ?

Comment: It is possible, but the distance between points should be positive, whether they are right or wrong.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you! You were right! I had made a silly error while computing the metric. So far, it seems to be a true metric. I will  test further